# Trigger on new notes

Tags: apex, custom-field, sharing

Whenever I create a new note for any parent object it is only available as ReadOnly for other users as they can't edit the same.

Is there any way we can write a trigger for new notes so that these can be available for other users as editable ?

Comment: I have never worked with notes, but this looks like a sharing issue to me. Can you change sharing settings in Notes? If so, have you tried setting the OWD to public read/write?

Comment: I recollect that Notes use the sharing rules of the object they are attached to. I see the question is tagged [salesforce-communities](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salesforce-communities) so that may also be contributing to the observed behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding to what @Keith has already commented on your post, Yes Notes has a standard sharing of "Controlled by Parent" which means whatever Organisation Wide Default sharing access that you've set for the Note's parent it will also be applied to the Notes records associated with that object. If you want your users to be able to modify the notes record, make sure that you've set the OWD access of the parent object to Read/Write.

Ex. If you want your users to be able to modify all of the Notes associated with an Account, you would have to set the OWD access of your Account object to Read/Write.

[Setting up Org Wide Defaults](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_sharing.htm&language=en)